# Oracle not connecting to remote server with .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an issue connecting to an oracle database from my test server. Bellow is my code snippet.

```
             using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
             using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
             private static string GetConnectionString()
     {
    String connString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=IP_Address)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=Service_Name)));User Id=hook;Password=Password;";

    return connString;
}

    private string ConnectingToOracle()
     {  
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())

        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            connection.Open();

            OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            string sql = " select * from sgmp.web_portal1   where account_no= '" + customerIdField.Value.ToString().Trim() + "'";
            command.CommandText = sql;
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())

                {
                    Session["ClientName"] = (string)reader["Customer_Name"];
                    return (string)reader["Customer_Name"];

                }
            }
            else
            {
                resp.Text = "Client ID '" + customerIdField.Value.ToString().Trim() + "' does not exist in records";
                return "none";
            }


            return "none";
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            resp.Text = ex.Message + " reasons ..";
            return "mmm";

        }
}
```

I got nothing as exception and I can't just connect.
Regards.
My first with Oracle after-all.

Comment: Besides a few missing `using` blocks and a vulnerability to SQL injection attacks due to not using `bind parameters` it looks fine. What happens when you execute it?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by 'I can't just connect'? How did you deduce that your connect wasn't successful? Perhaps you did indeed connect, but your query just don't return any rows. As a side note, you should use prepared statements instead of concatenating variable values into your SQL statements. Prepared statements (or whatever they're called in .NET) will perform much better and prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @nvoigt, I only got "reasons .." the 'ex.Messaage' displays nothing.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, I am using a known parameter to query the database. It works fine on command line

Comment: If you don't get the message, set a breakpoint and inspect the exception.

Comment: @nvoigt, When I did I had nothing (empty string) in the exception. And no inner exception either

Comment: What is the type of the exception?

Comment: @nvoigt, I got no exception at all. All I got was an empty string ("").

Comment: @Wale, you have a catch block. *Not* getting an exception in there is not possible. Use a debugger and look at `ex`.

Comment: @nvoigt, like I said, all I've gotten as exception is "" (empty string). If I have any exception at all, I might have been able to figure out the error.

Comment: Just a thought, could it be a library reference related? On the same server I have ODAC x64 installed and I could retrieve records from sql+ in the command prompt using the same user credentials used in my c# environment.

Comment: Wale, please read a turorial on exception handling first. The fact that the *Message* of the exception might be an empty string, still means you got an exception. The exception is more than the Message property.

Comment: I guys, I have been able to narrow it down. It works if the project is  tested within the visual studio environment (pressing F5 to run it) but when configured in IIS, the connection fails. What do I need to do in the IIS to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255084 All I needed to do was step 1 to 5